# How to apply ajax call into hover?

Tags: html, ajax, database, hover, imagemap

Having imagemap with hover, showing total no. of occurrence happened under the same location.

### Another php page: getOccCount.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(occurrence_id) FROM major_occurrence GROUP BY location_id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

But i'm not sure how to apply the ajax function into my hover div so that whenever hover over, the results will change as per different location_id.

```
<style type="text/css">
#map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 950px;
    height: 1211px;
    background: url(images/Campus-Map.jpg);
    background-size: 950px 1211px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#map li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#map li a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(blank.gif);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#map li a span {
    display: none;
}

#map li a:hover span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#map a.rpc {
    top: 1060px;
    left: 585px;
    width: 78px;
    height: 65px;
}
```

### Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $('#map>span').hover(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getOccCount.php',
                    data: "",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: GET,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id");
                        $.get("getOccCount.php", {location_id: location_id}, function (result) {
                            var result = data[0];
                            $('#map>span').html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
<body>
<html>
<ul id="map">
<li><a class="rpc" href="doRPMap.php?locID=1"><span><b>RPC</b></span></a> // and put the result inside here.          </li>
<ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please advice on this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the method:

```
  $.ajax({
                url: 'getOccCount.php',         
                data: "", 
                dataType: 'json',   
                success: function (data) ,
                method: "POST"  OR "GET"
}
```

Comment: Is it like the above changes? Then how should i apply into my map? inside the <span>

Comment: your syntax is not correct; i don't know why you'r performing two ajax requests (this same requests) ??      method: "GET"
                        {
                        var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id"); ???

Comment: need to echo back the results from getOccCount.php as a variable like: var result = result[0];
                                    $('#map').html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result);
                                    }

Answer (score 0):

for your first request :

```
$('#map').hover(function () {
     $.ajax({
      url: 'getOccCount.php',
      data: "",
      dataType: 'json',
      method: "GET",
      success: function (data){
            var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id");
            $.get("getOccCount.php", 
                  {location_id: location_id}, 
                   function (result) {
                      var result = result[0];
                      $('#map').html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' 
                              + result);
                   }
       }
                   });
                    });
```

where are you using data ?

```
url: 'getOccCount.php',
data: "", // input
dataType: 'json',

  success: function (data) //param
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#map').hover(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getOccCount.php',         
                data: "", 
                dataType: 'json',   
                method: GET,
                success: function (data) {
                var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id");
                $.get("getOccCount.php", {location_id: location_id}, function (result) {
                   var result = data[0];
                   $('#map').html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result);
                 }
               }
           });
        });
```

You can try  using the above set of codes.

Comment: then how should i put inside the <span>?

Comment: $('#map > span').hover(

Comment: I've made the necessary changes, but it's still not working for me. Can you please check on the edited codes above. Thanks.